# AngularJs: <object> tag usage in angularjs partial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, partials

I need to use <\object> tag or <\iframe> inside one of my partial html and use that html in another html page with ng-include. This is my try,

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- This part is not showing anything in the page -->
   <object ng-attr-data='"templates/widget_1.html"' type="text/html"></object>

   <!-- This part is showing page in view -->
   <div ng-include src='"templates/widget_2.html"'></div>    
</div>
```

OR

If I want to use <\iframe> within this page how can I use that?

Comment: Why you need to use object tag for this ? to achieve this, you need to write a directive and load the template by yourself

Comment: Actually I want to create a responsive web page, which height-width will change in different device in different resolution. But I've to show that effect in browser. So,using <\iframe> or <\object> I can change the viewport resolution. If you know some example on net can you share that with me? Thanks for your quick response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve this, you need to write a directive and load the template by yourself

```
app.directive("object", function ($templateCache, $http, $compile)
{
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        link: function ($scope, $element)
        {

            //load the external partial with http and cache into the $templateCache
            $http.get($element.attr("ng-attr-data"), {cache: $templateCache}).then(function (response)
            {
                //Fill the loaded html into the element
                $element.html(response.data);
                //compile the scope on it, to enable bindings.
                $compile($element.contents())($scope);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wrote this code but it gives me short of error,
    SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
    ...element.attr("ngAttrData")), {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(partialHtml

can you check and let me know where the missing separator is?

Comment: it is this second ")" after $element.attr("ngAttrData") and after function(partialHtml) missing "{" - Fixed. I am writing this on the fly and stackoverflows editor is for an developer forum just bad

Comment: gr8 also needed a "{" after .then(function(partialHtml) .. but still no luck html page is not loading in the view.. :(

Comment: any http error or something ? is the path to the template right ?

Comment: No error shows up..

HTML:
<div class="container">
    <object ng-attr-data='"templates/widget_1.html"' type="text/html"></object>
</div>

Comment: Directive:
app.directive("object", function($templateCache, $http,$compile){
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element){
          //load the external partial with http and cache into the $templateCache
          $http.get($element.attr("ngAttrData"), {cache: $templateCache}).then(function(partialHtml){
                //Fill the loaded html into the element
                console.info($templateCache);
               $element.html(partialHtml);
               //compile the scope on it, to enable bindings.
               $compile($element.contents())($scope);
          });
    }
  };
});

Comment: anything else which may I've missed?

Comment: í just found out. check my answer soon

Comment: Thanks a lot Konstantin Krass.. Now its working.. :)